# Equivalent for "ref new MainPage()" in C++ Windows Runtime

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

Let's imagine, that we have some application fully written on C++/CX. Root namespace for this application is `namespace SomeApp{...}`. And we have `ref class MainPage{...}` in this namespace. Also, there is `ref class App{...}`, derived from `Windows::UI::Xaml::Application` class. In method `App::OnLaunched(...)` we instantiate instance of MainPage class with code

`auto someVariable = ref new MainPage();`

What is equivalent for this code in raw C++ application(without using C++/CX extension)?
I tried to replace it with

`ComPtr<IInspectable> someVariable;
 auto className = HStringReference(RuntimeClass_SomeApp_MainPage).Get();
 RoActivateInstance(className, somevariable.GetAddressOf());`

But this call always returns "REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered".
I think, that C++/CX compiler replaces this code with:

- Direct call constructor of MainPage
- Attempt to find activation factory and after that call ActivateInstance.
- Some another code

What option is right?

Comment: Strong odds that your MainPage class is not actually located in another WinRT module.  In which case, yes, it calls the constructor directly and your RoActiveInstance() method is expected to fail.  Use the /FAcs compile option to look at the code generated by `ref new` to get insight.

Comment: Thank you for hint. 
Now I trying understand generated ASM code. 
And yes, it seems, constructor is called directly.